# I cannot launch React app on Windows. I have some problems with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a problem with launching react application on Windows 10. For that reason, I used command npx create-react-app . and unfortunately, I received the following bug:

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
Module build failed (from ../../c#/artur/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadLoader (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:812:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:956:15)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1367:12
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../c#/artur/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
```

My setup:
Node version: 16.13.1 LTS
Npm version: 8.3.0

I'm new in the world of front-end development, and I don't know why that happens. I found similar bugs on the Internet, but these answers didn't work for me.

Comment: Hello, in which folder are you trying to create it? 

Usually npx create-react-app SOMETHING (something will be your root folder), when you write ., it assumes, you already have an empty folder and want to configure the project there.

Comment: I tried to create that in ```C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\c#\artur\```, which was my current working directory. I don't think that it could cause this problem. I assume that problem can be somewhere in my webpack or node configuration, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: This folder wasn't empty for sure

Comment: There is no webpack configuration yet, npx create-react-app automatically will configure webpack for you and hide it's configuration in react-scripts library.  Try to create in seperate folder, like npx create-react-app test, it should work,  if you have node and npm installed, there is no reason not to work

Comment: Ok, I created a new project by command - ```npx create-react-app test``` and problem is the same as before.

Comment: What versions of  `nvm` and `npm` do you currently have installed? The `npx` package runner tool is only build in on `npm 5.2+`. You should also currently be inside the empty folder you wish to use for your new React app.

Comment: I don't have nvm, but npm in version 8.3.0. I tried to use command npx create-react-app test in empty folder and problem is all the time the same. I am searching a lot, but I can not fix this bug on my computer.

Comment: OK, I find the solution foe this buf. The problem is in the path. I moved the folder with react application to the desktop, and then app is running. Problem, which I had was by the '#' in the path to the folder.